# ArcGIS Administrator REST API

Tags: javascript, arcgis-rest-api, administration

Is it possible to use ArcGIS Administrator REST API via front-end (JavaScript) application? Every request I send is getting:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://.../arcgis/admin/system?f=pjson. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63130' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Request for data from standard REST API:

```
https://.../arcgis/rest/services/?f=pjson
```

works just fine.

What should I do to access allow my application to request data from ADMIN REST API?

Answer (score 1):

Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include more explanation about *how* to use what you have suggested, rather than just what to use.  Give some of the steps required in order to answer the question.